# Better method for writing out text line by line using Java Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream, export-to-csv

I would like to write out a list of lines of text to a csv using Java Stream API. However, I can build and filter out the lines which need to be written to the writer stream. But the part I use CSVWriter to write the line does not to be very Stream-style. How should I re-write the code?

```java
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public static void export(List<List<String>> data, Writer w) throws Exception{

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(w);    

    Stream.of(data)
        .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .forEach(row -> {
            writer.writeNext(row.toArray(new String[row.size()]));
        });

    w.flush();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Stream.of(data)`? That's a `Stream<List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Additionally, don't close `w` here, because you don't open it here. Closing things should (pretty much) always be the responsibility of the code which opens them. Perhaps you're intending something like `writer.flush()`?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this would be more "streamy":

```
data.stream()
     .filter(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)
     .map(row -> row.toArray(new String[row.size()]))
     .forEach(writer::writeNext);
```

Honestly, I'd have just gone with a for loop.

```
for (List<String> row : data) {
  if (Collections.isEmpty(row)) continue;
  writer.write(row.toArray(new String[row.size()]));
}
```

Comment: And [use `row.toArray(new String[0])`](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) to improve the performance while even simplifying the code. And use `row.isEmpty()` instead of spiffy 3rd party methods. If the list contains `null` elements, the responsible developer should get the exception thrown into their face.